# How do I fix the checkbox text spacing on pre-lollipop devices?

Tags: android, spacing, android-checkbox

I have a checkbox, with a style applied to it. On lollipop devices, the text is right next to the checkbox, but on pre-lollipop devices the text is far away.

How do I fix this?

```
 <style name="Widget.CheckBox" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:theme">@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_text</item>
    </style>
```

Pre-Lollipop (specifically 4.1.1)

[image]

Lollipop ⇦ This is how I want it to look on all devices

[image]

Comment: try using parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox" instead

Comment: That fixed it. Thx. Enjoy your upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the thread, I am posting the answer here:

The solution is to use `parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox"` to support lower APIs as well.